# How to make apache2 serve HTTPS on port 443 and non-standard ports?

Tags: server, apache2

Hi i want to change port in apache2. i was running owncloud on standard ports http=80 https=443. For some reasons i need to change https port from 443 to 8443. i have seen many solutions but i dont come to hundred percent result what i  want.
i just want that when i write my hostname "server" then i just see my owncloud page. when i write my ipadress then i no need to mention port number but when i write "server" then i need to mention port number 8443 then it works. i am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. i have tried everything on virtualhost and also by ports.conf.  kindly tell me some solution if someone know .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Browser knows default ports (80, 443). `http://` is also default. So when you write

```
server
```

Your browser actually makes a request

```
http://server:80/
```

If you type in

```
https://server/
```

Your browser will make a request

```
https://server:443/
```

In fact it is a little more complicated, because you cannot access the network name directly. Browser finds out IP of the server and makes request

```
http://<ip of server>:80/
```

and tells the server that the request is for `server`, because you can host also `server1`, `server2`,... on the same IP address.

You will not be able to make browser to request port 8443 by default. You will have to write it in the address.

The problems you are describing are not all clear to me, but it looks like they are all connected with apache configuration and the inability of browser to go to 8443 port by default.

When you have VirtualHost defined in apache, you must specify `ServerName`. Clients will arrive to the IP of server, but apache needs to know which server name was requested to send back the correct pages. If you access server only with IP the name will not be sent to apache and it will send back the default pages. I suspect that is happening in your case, because you say that browsing to IP works. I would suspect it works to default port numbers.

I hope I helped to clear out the questions at least a bit.

Comment: you mean to say there is no possibility that i just write server (without port number ) to come to the owncloud page? if yes than what would be your method csn please write it here. because if i just write my ipadress then i no need to mention port number.

Comment: You can just write your server name if you stay on standard ports or if you make a redirection. But that would mean that apache would still work on standard ports. On standard port it would just redirect to non-standard. You could make it listen on port 80 and then redirect to 8443. Take a look here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html to understand ports, IPs and names. Look here for redirect https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL